# After doing gulp serve does not load workbench.aspx

Tags: node.js, sharepoint, gulp, spfx

After executing gulp serve the sharepoint doesn't load and I don't know why after trying everything. But the server is working because when I execute https://localhost:4321/temp/manifests.js it loads all the manifest so it's very strange.
[image]

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp bundle",
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "test": "gulp test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "1.13.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-property-pane": "1.13.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "1.13.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "1.13.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "1.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "1.13.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-tslint-rules": "1.13.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "1.13.1",
    "@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.9": "0.4.47",
    "gulp": "~4.0.2",
    "ajv": "~5.2.2",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.1"
  }
}
```

And my serve.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/core-build/serve.schema.json",
  "port": 4321,
  "https": true,
  "initialPage": "https://enter-your-SharePoint-site/_layouts/workbench.aspx"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your serve.json file change initialPage to either Sharepoint site - for example "https://XXX.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx" - this will open Sharepoint workbench or in browser after running gulp serve go to the site "https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench.html" - this will open local workbench

The error is that you are trying opening workbench at site - https://enter-your-SharePoint-site/_layouts/workbench.aspx which clearly does not exists.

Please reffer to: [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part)

Comment: I want it to execute locally thats why I didn't  change the initial page link but I've tried before using this https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench.html and I get a Cannot GET /temp/workbench.html and a Content Security Policy of your site blocks some resources  issue in the chrome console

Comment: Have you tried following steps in MS doc? For example trusting cert - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment#trusting-the-self-signed-developer-certificate

Comment: Another questioni s if you are behind proxy: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/local-spfx-workbench-against-real-sharepoint-api-andrew-koltyakov/

Comment: Yes! I've done that too. Now I've changed the initialPage link to a one with a real sharepoint but the localhost:4321/temp/workbench.html  is still not working and is giving the same error

Comment: I think it's more related to CSP because is saying that " Refused to load the script 'https://localhost:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1 "because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". The problem is that idk where to write how the Content Security Policy should be in the project

Comment: @Brush could you solve this error> I am also facing the same error in many places, I tried in gitpod environment as well as windows devices the same error persists

Comment: @kl kl 
 I couldn't but you can still developing and see what the results are if you are connected to the cloud workbench.